# Remove item from ArrayList Java.. with need of an accessor

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Arraylist of rabbits.
Each rabbit has a `String` name and a `String[]` of information.

```
rabbit(String name, String[] informations)
```

I have these rabbits in a `ArrayList`, let's call it rabbitlist.

I want to make a method like:

```
public void removerabbit(String name)
```

I have to make some kind of while loop I guess or a for each loop to get the names out.
I have made an accessor getName() that gives the name of a rabbit.
Just having problems to wrap my brain around to figure out how. Should be simple.

Comment: for helping all, i would suggest you to include the code of `Rabbit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the name of your `Rabbit` is an unique identifier for the `Rabbit`, you can override the `equals` method of `Rabbit` to only check for the name. In that case, the `removeRabbit` method becomes very straightforward since the build-in remove method of the `ArrayList` uses the equals method to determine which element to remove.

```
public void removeRabbit( String rabbitName ){
  //just create a new Rabbit with rabbitName as name, 
  //and remove it from the list
  rabbitList.remove( new Rabbit( rabbitName ) ); 
}
```

In case that's not possible, you can iterate over the List. The following code will remove all Rabbits with the specified name. If you only want to remove the first, you should stop the loop once you removed the first rabbit.

```
public void removeRabbit( String name ){
  Iterator<Rabbit> rabbitIterator = rabbitList.iterator();
  while ( rabbitIterator.hasNext() ) {
    Rabbit next = rabbitIterator.next();
    if ( name.equals( next.getName() ) ){
      rabbitIterator.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u explain the Iterator ??
i know the while loop and if sentence.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator explains the concept of an Iterator pretty well

Comment: @Swupper - it sounds like you need to take the time to read the Oracle Java Tutorial ... or a good Java textbook.

Answer (score 0):

You need java.util.Iterator to be able to remove item during iteration on List

```
Iterator<Rabbit> it = rabbits.iterator();
String nameForRemove = "rabbitName";
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().getName().equals(nameForRemove)) it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate thru rabbitList to find rabbit with given name.Get its index on rabbitList,and remove it from rabbitList
Your code should be something like ,

```
public boolean removeRabbit(String name){
Rabbit rabbit;
Iterator it = rabbitList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    rabbit=it.next();
    if(name.equals(rabbit.getName()){    
        int index =rabbitList.indexOf(rabbit);
        //remove rabbit at this index,returns boolean
        return rabbitList.remove(index);
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

this will work may be with some changes...

EDIT :

```
public boolean removeRabbit(String name){
Rabbit rabbit;
int index;
Iterator it = rabbitList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    rabbit=it.next();
    if(name.equals(rabbit.getName()){    
        index =rabbitList.indexOf(rabbit);
        }
    }
//remove rabbit at this index,returns boolean
return rabbitList.remove(index);
}
```

this will work may be with some changes...

Comment: You should not remove elements from the list while iterating over it. Remove it from the iterator instead

Comment: @Robin : why cant v remove while iterating??